# Read data type from configs (Python)

Tags: python-3.x, config

I'd like to ask a question about data types in configs.
I have code in my notebook:

```
 train_config = {

'opt_cls': torch.optim.Adam,

'loss_fn': nn.CrossEntropyLoss(),

'metric_fn': f1_score,

'max_epochs': 10,

'opt_params': {

    'lr': 5e-4

},

'scheduler_cls': torch.optim.lr_scheduler.StepLR,

'scheduler_params': {

    'step_size': 4,

    'gamma': 0.55

},

'device': device

}
```

So now I'd like to distribute my code from notebook to .py files. As I think, it is logic to write
things like above in config files, like .yaml, .json. So, how can I easily read this config to not read strings, but types or functions?

I found solution on pyyaml site. But it requires to make classes, that are inherited from yaml.YAMLObject

But it is seems bad because if I decided to use, for example, my own loss function, I would write a lot of code to launch my experiment.